# efficiently decide whether a point in a data set has no close neighbors

Tags: r, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have a data set with about 10K points, each having 200 numeric descriptors.
Out of the 10K points, I would like to locate the outliers, which I define as the ones whose 10 nearest neighbors are far away (how far? the distance to the 10th neighbor is an outlier in terms of the other distances to the 10th neighbor, Outlier being defined as usual).

I have tried computing the entire distance matrix (10K x 10K), for every row apply partial sort to find the 10 nearest neighbors. Too expensive.

I have also checked out fast kNN options, but they are also too expensive.

The reason I think this can be done much more efficiently is because we don't really care about the actual distances, but only about their relative ranks.

A sample data matrix can be generated as follows:

```
df = matrix(rnorm(2000000), nrow = 10000, ncol = 200)
```

Any creative ideas?

Comment: How expensive is "too expensive"?   One kNN option gave about 35 seconds.

Comment: Since I have to do this many times I am looking for an approximate algorithm that will take a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First a question, why do have all 10 nearest neighbors to be far away? Are trying to avoid situations where 9 outlieres are close to each other?
- What is 'too slow'? Have you tries something like a [CoverTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree)? It has very fast kNN for high dimenionality.
- Speed up: Have you tries using L1/Manhattan/Taxi distance? It tends to be faster than euclidean distance.
- Generally speaking, with increasing dimensionality, kNN becomes increasingly meaningless because the average distance tends to become equal for all points, unless you have a strongly clustered dataset.
- A general idea: If you somehow calculated a distance that is known to be 'to far', you could simply use window queries to check whether there are any other points within a the 'too far' distance. Here I would suggest using the [PH-Tree](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree), it has very fast window queries especially when the result size is small (0 or 1 hits). It can also be adapted to abort the window after 1 or 10 hits and just return that there are more hits (or not). This should be faster than kNN. The problem is that window queries become increasingly inefficient with high dimensionality, at least when using L2-distance (euclidean). L1 should be more efficient.
- Also, have a look at [K-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). It don't know much about it, but it may also provide outlier detection. At the least, it should provide you with a way to determine how far 'too far away' is.
- One technique used (for example) in machine learning is dimensionality reduction. It's a bit tricky, but if you can reduce your dimensionality to 10 or so, kNN algorithms (or any other algorithm) may be much faster,

**EDIT**

I did some performance tests on my computer (I7-4790) using Java implementations: Dataset with 10K point and 200 dimensions (points slightly clustered, all between 0.0 and 1.0 in every dimension).

- CoverTree: Loading 10000 points takes 1.6 second. 10000 1-nearest neighbor queries is about 3.1 seconds.
- PH-tree: Loading 10000 points takes 0.07 seconds. 10000 window queries (window size chosen such that average result size=1) is about 5.5 seconds.

Comment: I am looking for multidimensional "outliers". The reason I put it in quotes is because this is my way of describing points that are isolated, far from most of the points in the data set. So the way I see an outlier in multidimensions is a point which is far away even from its closest neighbors. I haven't tried the other distance metrics, but it's a good idea.Too slow: the fastest I got was about 40 seconds. Since I have to do this many times this is too slow.

Comment: I understand you answered my first question, that would mean it should be enough to find only _one_ closest neighbor instead of ten. Many data structures have optimized algorithms for single-nearest neighbor.

Comment: Thanks! I am limited to using R, though. Do you know of any R implementations to CoverTree?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a CoverTree in are, probably not. But as far as I know, R can interface with Java, can it not?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea,
although I doubt it could work for random data.

```
# primarily for lag and lead
library(dplyr)

# sample data
df <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, drat, wt, qsec) %>%
  do(as.data.frame(scale(.))) %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!duplicated(.)))

knn <- 4L
distance <- 0.3

colwise_outlier <- sapply(1L:ncol(df), function(j) {
  column <- df[, j]
  order_ids <- order(column)
  column <- column[order_ids]

  n <- (knn + 2L) %/% 2L
  outlier <- column - lag(column, n=n, default=-Inf) > distance & 
    lead(column, n=n, default=Inf) - column > distance

  # return with original order
  outlier[order_ids]
})

is_outlier <- apply(colwise_outlier, 1L, function(r) {
  Reduce("&", r)
})

outliers <- df[is_outlier,]
```

What it does is it first checks each column in isolation,
and only marks a row as an outlier if at most `knn` values are within `distance` of it.
Then it only keeps rows where this condition was true in all columns.

EDIT: and you could even set different `distance` values for each column,
in case your data is not normalized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with checking each column in isolation is that a point can be considered a non-outlier in both dimensions individually, but an outlier for both. for example: the collection of points: `{(-3, 0.5), (-2.9, 0.6), (-3.1,0.4), (-3, 2), (-2.9, 2.1), (-3.1, 2.2), (1, 0.5), (1.1, 0.6), (0.9, 0.4), (1,2) }`. The last point is isolated from the others, although its `x` and `y` values are not outliers individually.

Comment: Certainly. It was just an idea, but it might be rarely suitable.